# Handle TYPO3 extbase controller action with middleware and URL pattern

Tags: typo3, middleware, extbase, typo3-extensions

I need some simple solution with TYPO3 middleware which identify URL pattern and return json response accordingly.

URL pattern: [https://example.com/[api]/[ext_name]/[controllerName]/[actionName]](https://example.com/%5Bapi%5D/%5Bext_name%5D/%5BcontrollerName%5D/%5BactionName%5D)

Eg:https://example.com/api/event/eventManagement/list

Based on this URL, it should call controller action. I following document example for writting middleware but it throws error.

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Middlewares.html#example
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Middlewares.html#example-usage
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/HowTo/Localization/Php.html#example-localization-middleware

[image]

Here below snippet also having the same error.

Here I registered middleware

```
<?php

return [
    'frontend' => [
        'picsoholic-rest' => [
            'target' => \Vendor\Ext\Middleware\RestMiddleware::class,
            'description' => 'Attempts to resolve the Extbase controller action',
            'after' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/prepare-tsfe-rendering'
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

services.yaml

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  Vendor\Ext\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'
    exclude: '../Classes/Domain/Model/*'

  Vendor\Ext\Middleware\RestMiddleware:
    public: true
```

and middleware class

```
<?php

namespace Devzspace\PicsoholicCore\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

class RestMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    /** @var ResponseFactory */
    private $responseFactory;

    /** @var RequestFactory */
    private $requestFactory;

    /** @var ClientInterface */
    private $client;

    public function __construct(
        ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory,
        RequestFactoryInterface $requestFactory,
        ClientInterface $client
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->requestFactory = $requestFactory;
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        // Check if request is for api.
        if ($request->getRequestTarget() === '/api') {
            // create logic for calling controller action for json response
        }
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }    
}
```

I want to handle GET, POST, DELETE, PUT request with the middleware. Any hint for creating it without third party extension?

Some solution to handle Extbase controller action with middleware rest URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to read the following section of the official docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#public

Pasted here for completeness:

> Direct access includes instantiation via GeneralUtility::makeInstance() with constructor arguments.

Also the next section mentions your error:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#errors-resulting-from-wrong-configuration

> If objects that use dependency injection are not configured properly,
> one or more of the following issues may result. In such a case, check
> whether the class has to be configured as public: true.
>
> ArgumentCountError is raised on missing dependency injection for
> Constructor injection:

I bet your middleware is not marked as public within DI, and marking it as public will solve the issue? Maybe you can also add more context from the stack trace? That should reveal how the instance is created.

Comment: Okay, that fix error with DI. But when I hit URL eg: https:demo.ddev.site/api it showing 404. But, https:demo.ddev.site/?api works.